# How should i manage table with many foreign keys inside?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working in a big project and one of my table needs to be linked into several other table. Currently, I've got one table for all data and one for the conditions (enabled or not). The conditions table have 4 foreign keys, and I feel like it's bad... What should I do ?

## Data Table

[image]

## Conditions Table

[image]

Comment: Then you feel bad, redisign your database sheme.

Comment: Hi @7IBO! Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be nice if you include your table structure

Comment: Data table : https://imgur.com/aU9fUrN Conditions table : https://imgur.com/FTVOCrQ

Comment: As @ErrBon says, it would be nice if you include your table structure, but as Text with your create statement, don't upload images or links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is superior to rely on facts than on feelings. So, instead of feeling bad, you need to ask yourself the following questions:

- is my application slow?
- do I have unnecessary redundancies?
- is there a possibility in my database for redundancies to creep in?
- do I have inconsistencies?
- is there a possibility in my database for inconsistencies to creep in?
- do I have difficulty in operating with my database due to its structure?
- is my database occupying too much space?

If any of your answers to the above is YES, then you will need to refactor your database. If all the answers is NO, then it's wise to postpone the worries until the moment when you start to see some problems creeping in. The reason of this is that the database design problems might be very different from those that you might suspect. So, it is possible that while you spend hours and hours into fixing some paper tigers you leave the real problems unresolved or, even worse, you might mishandle them and worsen the situation.

It is very common for new developers that they want to fix the universe in their project and, of course, this includes me back in the day as well. But, after spending a lot of time in making the database "perfect", later, when the database grew, the actual issues proved to be very different from the ones I expected and I realized how wrong I was. So, don't commit my mistake, learn from it and do not perform premature optimization. The main ingredient for the optimization is the problem. Without a problem it is difficult to reason for the optimization.

Now, if any questions were YES, then you will need to address the specific problem you have. I cannot properly answer all the points here, because that would require the writing of a book, which is of course outside the scope of a SO answer both in terms of length and style. Instead, let me put it this way:

You can copy your database and perform your optimization ideas both on your database and the copy. Over time, you will realize that you can shrink your table, at least by changing the types of fields where you can so they occupy a smaller space. You can create a third table that's having a foreign key both to your table and the table its foreign key was pointing to instead of the foreign key. So, if only a few records are linked, you will have only a few records in that relation table instead of millions of `null`s as value for the `foreign key`.

Comment: I still have some problems but considering the investment it would take to change it and the time I have left for the project knowing that it works for now I will let it go !

Comment: @7IBO no worries. You can always return to the problem later when it becomes a priority.